# Home folder in /etc

Tags: root, home

I was yesterday trying to mount a partition & playing around with firejail, when I realized I have a `${HOME}` folder (written just like that) in my `/etc` folder, even if my home folder is in the root folder (so now I have two, the `${HOME}` and the `/home`.) I'm wondering if this is a link I managed to somehow create. The folder appears as 0 bytes and empty from the GUI, but if I try to delete it from the command line, I get the error that the folder is not empty (plus I'm scared of deleting my entire home folder!).

What happened and why?
Thanks!

```
ls -al '/${HOME}'

total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 0 Dec 16 16:01 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 172 Dec 16 16:02 ..
```

Comment: What does `ls -al '/${HOME}'` say?

Comment: if you have `/${HOME}` AND `/home` and a `${HOME}` in `/etc` ... i.e. `/etc/${HOME}` then you have THREE, not TWO

Comment: Otherwise my bad, I have only two: /etc/$HOME and /home

Comment: Edit your post to add the output using [code block]s please. Command output is usually unreadable in comments.

Comment: Changed the post answering the comment.

Comment: I am unclear why both your Title and your text say the problem directory is within `/etc', but your `ls -al '/${HOME}'` is an absolute path name that omits `/etc` and apparently still works. Can you clarify ?

Comment: Please update the question with the output of `ls -dl '/${HOME}'`

Comment: @bxm you can infer that already from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to delete the unwanted empty directory as root quite safely:

```
rmdir '/${HOME}'
```

Or if you're not already root, then use `sudo`,

```
sudo rmdir '/${HOME}'
```

Notice the single quotes. These tell the shell not to treat any characters in the string specially, so it will not expand `${HOME}` as a variable - it will literally use the sequence of seven characters.

Incidentally, if you had tried `rmdir /${HOME}` you would have attempted to delete your own home directory, because the shell would have expanded `$HOME` as the value of your home directory and then executed `rmdir` with the resulting string. Fortunately this target won't have been empty and you'll have received an error message ending, `Directory not empty` with a consequent no action taken.

Comment: I see, so it's about escaping characters. Thank you!